# Why did TaleSpin reuse characters from The Jungle Book (1967)?

Tags: crossovers, the-jungle-book, talespin

*TaleSpin* is a 1990s adventure cartoon featuring Baloo and few other characters from the 1967 The Jungle Book film.

Why did the creators of *TaleSpin* decide to reuse those characters rather than create new one? And why that film and not a different one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Time constraints

[Jymn Magon answers this on Animation Source](https://www.animationsource.org/talespin/en/custom_questions/&nump=1338&numg=157)

> We never intentionally thought of TS as a "spin-off" or even a parody of Jungle Book. As I mentioned, we were in a **time crunch to create a new series**. We know Baloo was a great character (from the B Players development) and we weld that onto the Launchpad McQuack air delivery service idea from Duck Tales. Those were the roots of the series.

Further as to why that film to source characters from:

> Kit came next, because the dynamic of the eager son (Mowgli) and the bad role model father (Baloo) was so clearly delineated in Jungle Book. Next came the Cheers angle with Rebecca as inexperienced boss and surrogate mother for Kit. Wildcat was based on the drugged out pilot character from "Fandago" (go rent it). Only after these elements were in place that we decided to add a neutral territory (like Rick's Cafe American from Casablanca) and who better to run it than King Louie??! Shere Khan was added even later. **So as you can see, we didn't start off with a Jungle Book take-off... it was strictly the Baloo father figure/ lazy (censored) man that we were interested in.**

In short they were hoping to use the aforementioned character dynamic to save time in creating new characters.

Comment: In the past 2 decades Disney has spent a lot of time developing characters over multiple series. I wonder if the success of TaleSpin and its origination was perhaps inspiration for doing this on purpose. The culmination of this being a full exploration of the Marvel universe via cinema.